# Cannot convert value of type 'Character' to type 'String' in coercion

Tags: swift, string

In Swift, I would expect the following to be a perfectly valid code:

```
let snailCharacter: Character = ""
let snailString = snailCharacter as String
```

But apparently, it produces an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Character' to type 'String' in coercion

Solution to this is to use `String` initializer like this:

```
let snailString = String(snailCharacter)
```

I thought `Character` is kind of a subset of `String`, so that surprised me. Why is it forbidden to cast `Character` to `String`?

I'm using Swift 4 in Xcode 9 beta 4.

Comment: A `String` is a collection of `Character`s. You cannot cast because that are different types.

Comment: It's just a design decision, so only who designed Swift `Character` can explain why. In Swift Standard Library, `Character` is designed as a completely different thing than `String`, which has an efficient internal representation for holding a single BMP-character. So, the relationship between `Character` and `String` does not match any of the cases where `as`-casting provided: -- upcasting, bridging, annotating literal types, disambiguating overloaded functions. `Int8` can be considered to be sort of a subset of `Int16`, but you cannot use `as`-casting to convert `Int8` to `Int16`.

Comment: Arriving here to address the error, I think the question provided the solution, the answer was just a bonus :) +1 for both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html), you can see, that `Character` is just one of the several representations of `String` in `Swift` (emphasis added to the relevant parts by me)

> A string is a series of characters, such as "hello, world" or
>   "albatross". Swift strings are represented by the String type. The
>   contents of a String can be accessed in **various ways, including** as a
>   collection of Character values.

In `Swift`, `String` is not just an array of `Character`s unlike in some other languages. In `Swift`, `Character` is just a way to represent a `String` instance in a certain way. `String`s can be represented using `View`s, such as `CharacterView`, `utf8View`, etc.

One of the key principles behind the architecture of `Swift`'s `String` type was Unicode correctness, which is one of the reasons `String`s are not just simply an array of `Character`s.

For more information about the changes to `String` in `Swift4`, see the [String Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md).

To be more specific about why casting doesn't work. There are two kinds of castings, type casting and bridge-casting. Type casting is only possible between classes, where inheritance is involved. You can either upcast a subclass to its superclass, which always succeeds or you can try to downcast a superclass to a subclass, which only works if a subclass instance was first upcasted to its superclass.

It should be quite clear from the above explanation why type casting doesn't work between `Character` and `String`, since the neither of the two types inherit from each other.

For bridge casting, this is a method Apple introduced for interoperability between some `Swift` and `Foundation` types, such as `String` and `NSString`, but since both `String` and `Character` are `Swift` types, bridge casting has nothing to do with this problem either.

Comment: Does it explain why it can't be casted?

Comment: @RoboRobok I have added some more points for clarity, check my answer now and tell me if it is clear enough.

Answer (score -2):

First you need a textual representation of that. You can convert to `String` only the description of a `Character` like this

```
let snailCharacter: Character = ""
let snailString = snailCharacter.description as String
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. `description` property is meant to represent variable for debugging, and using it in this case just because it's `String` is not very good idea. Also, this is already a `String`, so your `as String` is redundant.

Comment: The question was about the *reasoning* behind the forbiddance of this kind of casting and not about ways of the conversion itself.